# Testing RxJava exception with TestSubscriber

Tags: java, junit, rx-java

I am trying to write test cases for a function which return some data if validation passes else throws exception

```
private String validate(Test test) {
    //Validation Logic which returns null or throws Exception

    }

    public Observable<Test> create(Test test) {
        return Observable
                .just(validate(test))
                .flatMap(x -> testRepository
                        .create(test));
    }
```

Test case for the same

```
@Test
    public void Should_ThrowException_When_NoData() {
       Test test = sampleTest();
        TestSubscriber<Test> subscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
        testService
                .create(test)
                .subscribe(subscriber);
        subscriber.awaitTerminalEvent();
        Throwable thrown = subscriber.getOnErrorEvents().get(0);
        assertThat(thrown)
                .isInstanceOf(CustomException.class)
                .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("errorId", 102);

    }
```

But the test case is failing on testService.create itself.

What is the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: It fails because you call `validate()` before its return value is used for creating the Observable.

Comment: Ok, then how can it be fixed?

Comment: `fromCallable(() -> validate(test))`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you post your code as answer so that I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because you call `validate()` before its return value is used for creating the Observable. Instead, you can call `fromCallable(() -> validate(test))` and get the execution of `validate` deferred.